# Understanding how dfm_groups works with no group added

Tags: r, quanteda

Building off of this question: [Interpretation of dfm_weight(scheme='prop') with groups (quanteda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856654/interpretation-of-dfm-weightscheme-prop-with-groups-quanteda/56858551?noredirect=1#comment100297940_56858551)

If i have the function:

```
     plot_topterms = function(data,text_field,n,...){

  corp=corpus(data,text_field = text_field) %>% 
    dfm(remove_numbers=T,remove_punct=T,remove=c(stopwords('english')),ngrams=1:2) %>%
    dfm_weight(scheme ='prop') %>% 
    dfm_group(groups=...) %>% 
    dfm_replace(pattern=as.character(lemma$first),replacement = as.character(lemma$X1)) %>% 
    dfm_remove(pattern = c(paste0("^", stopwords("english"), "_"), paste0("_", stopwords("english"), "$")), valuetype = "regex") %>% 
    dfm_remove(toRemove)
  freq_weight <- textstat_frequency(corp, n = n)

  ggplot(data = freq_weight, aes(x = nrow(freq_weight):1, y = frequency)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity')+
    facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = nrow(freq_weight):1,
                       labels = freq_weight$feature) +
    #scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
    theme(text = element_text(size=20))+
    labs(x = NULL, y = "Relative frequency")
}
```

and I don't pass in a grouping variable so I do something like:

`plot_topterms(df,textField,n=10)`

I get an output with the group variable equal to `all`. This should be equivalent to not even having the dfm_group line correct? And if thats the case, if I have a relative frequency of 60 for the word `fun`, does this mean that 60% of all documents  contain that word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of the "all" group is correct.  The effect of not specifying `groups` in `textstat_frequency()` is that the group will default to "all".  In your function, you never pass a `groups` argument in the call to this function, so that it will always be "all", even if you have already grouped the dfm through the `dfm_group()` call inside your function `plot_topterms()`.

A value of 60 for a feature in this plot would mean that the sum of the relative term frequencies (within document) for this feature is 60.  If you look at [the question you reference above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856654/interpretation-of-dfm-weightscheme-prop-with-groups-quanteda/56858551) then you will see how this works for the simple example.  `a`'s relative frequency in text1 was 0.20 and 0.67 in text2, so the `textstat_frequency()` sums those two into 0.87.  Your 60 is analogous to this 0.87.

This is *not* the same as document frequency, which is the number of documents in which a feature occurred (at least once).  If you want to know the features' document frequencies (which was your interpretation), then you should be plotting `docfreq` from the `textstat_frequency` return, not `frequency`.

I would note however that `plot_topterms()` is not a well-designed function.

- It relies on several variables that are not local to the functions, namely `toRemove` and `lemma`.
- It will not correctly pass the `...` in the `dfm_group()` call.  You should explicitly specify a `groups` argument in the function signature instead.

If we were designing a new function for the package, we would create a new function `textplot_frequency()` that plotted a return from `textstat_frequency()` that basically implemented just the `ggplot()` call after the user has built the `textstat_frequency` object.  This could make smarter use of the group variable built in to every `textstat_frequency` object, so that those in which the only group is "all" will plot this as a single facet.